# Compile SASS @functions with node-sass

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

While using `node-sass` to compile my SASS files to CSS, the SASS functions are not getting compiled. However, no errors are thrown during when I run the command.

My function is defined in a `_function.scss` partials which is imported on a `settings.scss` file which in turn gets imported across all of my SASS files.

```
@function rem($value) {
  $remValue: calc($value / $root) + rem;

  @return $remValue;
}
```

Using the function

```
.tabs__trigger {
  height: rem(5);
 }
```

After compiling the files using `node ./node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass -o dist/css src/scss` the resulting CSS file have

```
.tabs__trigger {
  height: calc($value / $root)rem;
}
```

So, is there any flag or configuration to compile SASS functions using node-sass?

Comment: Calc is a reserved word in css, of I'm not mistaken there is a different syntax in sass.

Comment: @cloned there isn't.  It's the fact that the variables weren't interpolated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [interpolate](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) the variables in order for them to compile correctly.

```
@function rem($value) {
  $remValue: calc(#{$value} / #{$root}) + rem;

  @return $remValue;
}
```

Assuming you want to create a rem value based of the root you can do the following:

```
@function rem($value) {
  @return #{$value / $root} + rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @dantheman this helped to some extend. However, now the compiled CSS have `height: calc(3 / 16)rem;`
Is anything wrong with the function? or other alternative to do this?

Comment: @MalabyaTewari I've updated the answer for you

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot dantheman. Though a minor update to the function
`$remValue: #{$value / $root}rem;`